# How to rename shapefiles using R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I am just trying to rename my file names from the list shp.import. But `file.rename` function doesn't helps.

`shp.import <- list.files()
file.rename(from=shp.import, to=sub(pattern="dat_SPDF_", replacement="", shp.import))
file.rename(from=shp.import, to=sub(pattern=".shp", replacement="", shp.import))
shp.import`

Here I need to remove 'dat_SPDF_' and '.shp' from the file name. I also didn't find any examples with stringr library.

Comment: What is the output from `list.files()`? What errors or problems are you seeing from running your code? Could you also provide an example of before and after your desired rename? Please edit your question with these details.

Comment: I have renamed in the folder but not in rstudio.

Comment: How to rename using with stringr library?